# .NET MVC custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering if I could create a routing map with one more higher level than the controller. The typical routing would include "/controller/action/id". What I am looking for is something like "section/controller/action/id" or "controller/section/action/id". How can i do this?

Comment: Need more clarification:
What does your section look like?  Is it a path or a token?
And do you know all your sections before hand or do you want a route that can handle any section?

Comment: Is this not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623605/net-mvc-custom-routing/1623624

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. Just create a route the URL of which is, for example

`path/to/my/application/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

...and supply a default controller and action as usual.

A concrete example of this is

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "AdminHome", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

This will map, for example, the following URLs:

```
/admin/                   => AdminHomeController.Index
/admin/adminhome/         => AdminHomeController.Index
/admin/other/             => OtherController.Index
/admin/statistics/view/50 => StatisticsController.View(50)
```

Note, though, that if you also have a default route, for example like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

...then controller action methods in the Admin routing may also be accessible via this route. Use the [URL Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to find out for sure.

Comment: To avoid any confusion, that should be `"pathToApplication/ExtraBits/{controller}/..."` where `pathToApplication` is the root of the IIS Application (i.e. "`~`").