# MVC3 URL Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am wanting to create a website that dynamically maps routes in the following fashion:

http://domain/MyCategory1
http://domain/
http://domain/MyCategory1/MySubCategory

So far I've added in a new route to Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
"IFAMainCategory", // Route name
"{IFACategoryName}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSubCategories", IFACategoryName=1} // Parameter defaults
);
```

But this then messes up the default route that comes as standard.

Is there any way I can control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your routes:

```
 routes.MapRoute("MyCustomRoute", "MyCategory1/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "MyCategory1", action = "MySubCategory", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

// Then the default route
```

Basically, since you've just made one giant route catcher, all routes match to that one. You need to go specific if you want to map a specific route to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include MyCategory1 in the route name

```
routes.MapRoute( "IFAMainCategory", 
// Route name "MyCategory1/{IFACategoryName}", 
// URL with parameters new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSubCategories", IFACategoryName=1} // Parameter defaults );
```

Check out this other post for example, and check out Route Debugger

[.NET MVC custom routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623605/net-mvc-custom-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you're going to achieve what you want directly.

You need some way to separate the routes, like placing your "categories" in a folder:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IFAMainCategory", // Route name
                "categories/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSubCategories", IFACategoryName=1 } 
            );
```

The other option is you could register a route for every parent category before the default route on App Start:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IFAMainCategory 1", // Route name
                "MyCategory1/{subcategory}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSubCategories", IFACategoryName=1, subcategory =  UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "IFAMainCategory 2", // Route name
                "MyCategory2/{subcategory}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "GetSubCategories", IFACategoryName=2, subcategory =  UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```